# How can I deal with multiprocessing?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I try to tune the learning rate parameter in XGBoost by using this part of program:

```
model = XGBClassifier()
learning_rate = [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3]
param_grid = dict(learning_rate=learning_rate)
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=7)
grid_search = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid, scoring="neg_log_loss", n_jobs=-1, cv=kfold)
grid_result = grid_search.fit(X, label_encoded_y)
```

but an error occurring in that line GridSearchCV:
ImportError: [joblib] Attempting to do parallel computing without protecting your import on a system that does not support forking. To use parallel-computing in a script, you must protect your main loop using 'if **name** == '**main**'.

but when I change the value of n_jobs=-1 to n_jobs=1 the error goes out but I want it to run using all cores.
please, how I can overcome this error?

Comment: The error message is clear. Read the multiprocessing documentation, especially the part about `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

Answer (score 1):

Place your main loop above (along with any additional necessary code) inside a function called main() and at the end of your script put
`if __name__ == '__main__': main()`
This way you will protect the loop from accidental start when you import the script contents to some other program.